# Rails - PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So it's a very beginner question, I am getting the following error. I know that I need to convert it over to string type. I have tried many kinds of conversion method, but yet to work. Hard coding this field as something like '2018-01-01' works. The param content that I am getting back is correct. It is the type that is creating this error. I even try to convert it over to a date type and tested the type and returned true, but still fail to succeed. Let me know if this makes sense.

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "order_date" is of type date but expression is of type integer
```

My expresson

```
created_at = (params[:created_at])
```

Have tried

```
created_at = (params[:created_at]).to_date
created_at = (params[:created_at]).to_s
```

I am trying to get the `params[:created_at]` from the payload and use the following code to insert into psql. So I think I should go with the create action. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
def create
  created_at = (params[:created_at])
  puts created_at
  sql = "insert into api.salesorder(site, order_date,sale_type,sales_rep,terms,customer_number) values('WHS',#{created_at},'CUST','HOUSE','PRE','123456')"
  results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

Comment: If your `param[:created_at]` is correct, you shouldn't have to do anything to it. Maybe give us some more example code and we can help.

Comment: Your error message says `order_date` but the example code uses `created_at` - which one are you having problems with? In rails, the `created_at` and `updated_at` are set automatically - you don't have to do anything with them.

Comment: Please see post again for more codes. Very bad at this. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share the form or front end that is passing in the `created_at` param?

Comment: ```module.exports = function(payload, actions) {
       let createdDate = payload.created_at.split("T")[0].toString();
  return actions.http.post(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {created_at: createdDate}).then(({ data }) => {
    console.log('data is ', data)
  })
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to use direct SQL (which I advise against in Rails, since Rails does the SQL for you), you need to change it to wrap your date in single quotes.

```
sql = "insert into api.salesorder(site, order_date, sale_type,sales_rep, terms, customer_number) values('WHS','#{created_at}','CUST','HOUSE','PRE','123456')"
```

A better solution would be to leverage Rails to do the SQL work for you. Something like this:

```
# in app/models/salesorder.rb
class Salesorder < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# in app/controller/salesorder_controller.rb
class SalesorderController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @salesorder = Salesorder.new
    @salesorder.order_date = params[:created_at]
    @salesorder.site = 'WHS'
    @salesorder.sale_type = 'CUST'
    @salesorder.sales_rep = 'HOUSE'
    @salesorder.terms = 'PRE'
    @salesorder.customer_number = '123456'

    if @salesorder.save
      redirect_to @salesorder, notice: 'Salesorder was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much! Didn't know I had to put quotes on the #{variable}. As for the better solution, I know that I shouldnt use direct SQL, but this is server/database living outside of my computer and I am not even sure how to access it via the rails method if not direct sql(I am very beginner level at this A_A). Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `created_at = Date.parse(params[:created_at])`, but i don't think it's nescessary. Some more information might be helpful. Is your params an `integer` type?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but the error I am getting back says it is an integer type. The data I am looking at on my terminal/logs shows it as string. Please see post again for my edits and more codes

Comment: Tried your method, it is still returning the following error. (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "order_date" is of type date but expression is of type integer

Comment: What is the class of `params[:created_at]` ? Use `binding.pry` in the create method and determine class of `params[:created_at]`.

Comment: I think I figure out what my problem is. I shouldn't be using intepolation with sql queries.

Comment: I don't understand why you are writing sql statements ? Stringify params before sending could also solve your problem.